Properties of special curves: cardioid, astroid, tractix, and so on
The question originated while trying to find coordinates of key points in a cardioid.
It is easy to find references listing points of interest and properties for conic sections online. Below are some examples:
$$Parabola$$

$$Hyperbola$$

$$Ellipse$$

Knowing these points or clever constructions (such as the string and the two points for the ellipse) helps you transfer these ideas into engineering applications.
Now,
in trying to find points and properties for interest for other curves, such as the cardioid, nephroid, astrix, etc (in fact, it turns out there are many curves).
QUESTION: Is there any resource or compilation online that lists and categorizes the key points, properties, or geometric constructions of these and other curves?
For instance: Critical points (cusps, nodes, inflection points, etc.), parametric or polar representations, applications or intuitive constructions (e.g., string-and-pin setups like for conics).

Below are some examples of constructions but you can notice points are often not labelled in these whereas they are for conics.
$$\text{Cardioid}$$
 
$$\text{Nephroid}$$

$$\text{Tractix and Catenary}$$


Do you know the mathcurves site ?

I did not. That is a great resource!
